# How to install and use bower in windows 7

Tags: node.js, git, bower, bower-install, npm-install

I'm a beginner in using bower and had searched all over the internet for installing the bower but couldn't find step by step method for installing the bower. If you please help me for this I shall be very thankful to everyone.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First you need to install node.js which you can do here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/.
Once you have node installed you need to open a command prompt window. To install bower you enter the command `npm install -g bower`

Comment: thanks . can you send me the link full language details of polymer and also let me know how to use Polymer?

is Polymer is better then the wordpress??

Comment: Here are the getting started docs for polymer https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/getting-the-code.html. It's hard to say if it is better/worse than wordpress because they are two completely different things. Wordpress is a CMS, while polymer is more of  a collection of/way of creating widgets you can use like html elements.

Answer (score 8):

Follow the steps below to get Node/NPM, Bower & Git up and running for a new project.

1.[Download & Install Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)

2.Install Bower Globally - `npm install -g bower`

3.[Download & Install Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

4.Create your Project Directory and `cd` into the project directory just created.

5.Initialize Git in your project - `git init`

6.Initialize your `package.json` for NPM dependencies - 
`npm init` (Answer the questions that it asks)

7.Initialize your `bower.json` for Bower dependencies - `bower init` (Answer the questions that it asks)

#### package.json & bower.json Docs

[NPM `package.json` Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)
[Bower `bower.json` Docs](https://github.com/bower/spec/blob/master/json.md)

Comment: thanks @SeanKelleyx
by installing the #GIT and bower. i have to write a command into the node js to for the package.json and bower.json?